# ios UIScrollview pass scroll event to superview

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uipangesturerecognizer

I have a UIView, and the UIView can detect a pan gesture to move this UIView to left. then I add a scrollview to this UIView, and this scrollview also can move to left and right(scroll's method), in the scrollview view, I add a UITableView that can scroll up and down and The UITableCell can detect UITapGesture. 
  If I not use UIScrollView, when scroll the tableview to left(the tableview can not scroll to left), the UIView can detect the pan gesture and move to left, but if I use the UIScrollView, when I scroll the tableview ,the move event is detected by the UIScrollView and can not pass to it's superview ,the UIView.
  How can I do to pass the move event to the UIView if the UIScrollView can not scroll because It's contentoffset.x == 0 and can not scroll to left, So my UIView can detect the pan gesture and move to left.
  Thank you!